# CSS Master Styling Clarification

Tags: css

I have seen conflicting information about how to use a master style sheet and have experienced some bugs when testing methods. Just want to get clarification on the proper way to do this.

I would like to store cross website branding styles in a master global.css sheet and make page specific adjustments on a second .css file.

For example, this code would live on the master sheet:

```
#headline1{
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 96px;
    letter-spacing: -1.5px;
}
```

and this code would be page specific:

```
.headline {
        color: #FFFFFF;
        text-align: center;
}
```

I have recently read something that said you should not use ID in this manner. I've also run into issues when using it multiple times in the same grouping. I initially tried doing this using just classes instead of the ID, but it never worked. Not sure why.

Is this method considered proper? If not what is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you create a master.css with:

```
.headline {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 96px;
  color:#000
  letter-spacing: -1.5px;
}
```

You can build upon/replace it per page as long as your custom css comes after the master.css

```
.headline {
  font-size: 45px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Quick example of a page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="master.css"/>
<style>
  .headline {                      // 
    font-size: 120px;              // size overides master
    color: #FF0000;                // color overides master
    text-align: right;             // added alignment, which is overiding the browsers base css
   }
</style>
```

I'm not sure if this is quite what you are looking for, but I hope it helps

In the example you provided a can only assume you have something along the lines of:

```
<div id="headline1"><span class="headline">Title</span></div>
```

This would basically mean any style applied to the div, the span would inherit unless told otherwise.

To further expand on this, you can also use inline styles `<span style="color:#FFF">` which will dominate any other styling UNLESS an `!important;` has been added to a style element.